Cannot get an Angular reactive forms AsyncValidatorFn to debounce and set control error
I have an Angular reactive form where a form group has an expensive validation, so I wanted to try and debounce the call to the actual validation.
I found many other posts on this, for example here, and also this running example which seemed to be doing what I want.
However, when I use the above, it just never sets the errors on the control.
I forked the above example here, but also included trying to display the actual error...
<div>{{userGroup.errors ? userGroup.errors[isUserIdFree] : "none" }}</div>
<div>{{getError(userGroup.errors)}}</div>

Where I also pass the errors object to getError.
As in my application, errors is just never set.
I seem to get the same in anything method where I try to have a debounce, the errors is just never set.
Why is this, and is it really possible to debounce the async validation?

Another method is to only perform the validation on blur
['', {validators: Validators.required, asyncValidators: IsUserIdFreeValidator.createValidator(this.userService), updateOn: 'blur'}]


Angular auto unsubscribes pending API calls so they get cancelled before new ones get initiated, so there is no need for debounce, since it taken care of internally.
import {
  AsyncValidatorFn,
  ValidationErrors,
  AbstractControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { UserService } from './user-service';

export class IsUserIdFreeValidator {
  static createValidator(_userService: UserService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    console.log('Static factory call');
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
      console.log('Inner AsyncValidator call');
      const id = control.value;
      return _userService.isUserIdFree(id).pipe(
        map<boolean, ValidationErrors>((isUserIdFree) => {
          return !isUserIdFree ? { isUserIdFree: `${id} is taken` } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
}

The reason, you are not getting the form errors, might be due to an old angular bug in angular 6, it does not exist in newer versions of angular.
The fix for this, is to directly access the control errors, using a getter method instead.
App TS:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserService } from './user-service';
import { IsUserIdFreeValidator } from './user-validator';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  show = true;
  userGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private userService: UserService) {
    this.userGroup = fb.group({
      id: [
        null,
        [Validators.required],
        [IsUserIdFreeValidator.createValidator(this.userService)],
      ],
    });
  }

  get idControl() {
    return this.userGroup.get('id');
  }

  public getError(val): void {
    console.log(val ? JSON.stringify(val) : 'null');
  }
}

App HTML:
<p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle</button>
<form *ngIf="show" novalidate [formGroup]="userGroup">
  <input formControlName="id" />
</form>
<div>
  {{
    (idControl && idControl.errors && idControl.errors['isUserIdFree']) ||
      'none'
  }}
</div>
<div>{{ getError(userGroup.errors) }}</div>
<p>Form: {{ userGroup.value | json }}</p>

Service:
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  isUserIdFree(id: string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('Service call: ', id);
    return this.httpClient
      .get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' +
          (Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 2).toString()
      )
      .pipe(map((data: any) => data.id === 1));
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thanks for that, I do see the service is now called all the time. I don't actually have a http call in my real app, just a heavy calculation being call more than necessary. It is async as I have async calls in it (eg getting values from ng/rx store, and other) I have a form group, and validation seems to be called for each field, but I only need the call once. Would you know the Angular bug details, so I can see when it's fixed (my real app is running v16.1.6 - so 2 behind - soon to update but this could accelerate the process)

@peterc check by doing console.log, if the process is cancelled midway

@peterc updated with alternative approach

Thanks for that. In my "real app" blur would not help as my controls are actually popups (e.g. a select and date time picker). I have managed to get rid of the unwanted calls by waiting will I have set the form, then set a flag bool (e.g. formIntialized), and exit the validation function until this flag is set to true. Still be very interested in the debounce though, as I am sure this will come up in the future.

Thanks for the suggestions @Naren, will leave open though to see if there does come a solution to actually use a debounce

Update - using "flags" has become trouble some, so I am still very interested in any debounce solutions that may work.

Still not answering this question, but a workaround I have found to use debounce is to not use a validator at all. I have subscribed to valueChanges, and then just call a Subject with a debounced subscription, that then calls an plain old method to validated, and then manually set the error on the controls using setErrors. For may case at least this seems to work fine and very efficiently (as I need to run validation on ANY changes as I have cross validation between fields AND rows in a ControlArray)

@peterc it's better with the flag approach, what issues did you have with it? Maybe share a stackblitz with the issue highlighted for others to check using the same

Oops I meant the comment to be under the main question. In my "real app" the validation is complicated, that's why found the simple used the sample for debounce. Just doing it manually has ended up being a LOT simpler for what I wanted to do (.ie using a debounce did not need flags being set all over the place which is was getting to)
